# Display a unique number for each visitor?

Tags: php, web, numbers, visitor-pattern

I'd like to create a page on my website where a UNIQUE number (1, 2, 3, and so on...) would be displayed for each visitor.

For example, if visitor A connects firt, number "1" would be displayed. Then if visitor B connects at the same time, number "2" would be displayed.

But here's the hard part : if visitor A disconnect from the website, the next visitor (C) would see number "1" on the page (if no other visitor has connected meanwhile).

Can some "God of programmation" help me doing this ?

Thanks a lot !
Chris.

Comment: There is no "God of programmation" in here to write your code.First try something and ask question if you are stuck with something.

Comment: Hi User016, thank you for your answer !
I'd like to but I do not know how to. I'm not expecting someone to code it for me : I'd just like some help (someone who can tell me how to) :)

Comment: You will have to persist the unique number in some form, possibly in the database

Comment: Hi Sajuna, thanks for your answer :)
What do you mean by "persist" (i'm french) ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't "connect" and "disconnect" from websites. You make an HTTP-Call to GET the page, then there is no further communication. Each HTTP-Call is a seperate connect and disconnect.

BUT: You can use AJAX to check back every second or so to tell the server you are "still there". (Like a heartbeat signal)

It is possible to do, but not elegant.

Question (1): What if: A gets 1, B gets 2, A "disconnects", does C get 1 or 3?, ...

Try:

User makes a call, save his number and a "timeout"-time (now + 3 seconds) in a database, open up a session where you store the "id" of the row that belongs to the user.

Write a Javascript-Script that does AJAX-Calls every second to update the "timeout"-time in the database for the user.

How to get the numbers:

Use a query to check if the numbers weren't in the timeout (count the number of "users" and check if the max value of the "number" you saved is equal to that, or so...) 
If thats so, you can give the new user a greater number, else you have to find which number isn't taken or start with 1 all again (depends on your answer of Question 1)

Question 2: Why do you want to programm this?

Comment: Using an arbitrary (e.g. auto increment) number would be much easier.

Comment: I realize i forgot to say I'm a beginer (still learning)... I don't understand... :( sorry :X

Comment: What's the use for the number? Can't it be just "any" unique number?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you use to keep track of the users, mysql, redis, or the svr can hold data between requests, like nodejs.

Whatever, I think you need to keep 2 things,

1. the number list returned, in order, like [1, 5, 19 ...]
2. the total number of vistors now, like 20

So, when some visitor came, do these things in a single thread:

1. check the returned number list firstly, if not empty, pop the first one out and return;
2. Or, just increase the total num and return the new number.

When the visitor leave, insert its number to right position of the returned list, and decrease the vistor count.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand anything... :(

Answer (score 0):

Because the HTTP protocol is `stateless` there is no reliable way of achieving this.

As far as the server is concerned I am only actually connected while I am downloading a page and its contents. That may involve 10's if not hundreds of actuall connections. Once that is complete I am disconnected.

I may stare at the page for 10 hours but I am not connected.

Using PHP you may then consider making use of the session, storing that on a database would allow you to count sesion rows to get your next 'connection number', however this also is unreliable in this respect. The session gets created on my first conversation with a php script that creates a session. The session will exist and be refreshed by subsequent conversations with your scripts, but it will then stay in existance until it's timout period expires.

I may have gone somewhere else long before that timeout occurs. So this too is unreliable for your requirements.

The javascript 'heartbeat' idea mentioned by @SpazzMarticus has possibilities but as I can disable javascript it too is unreliable. It would also increase your server load by a hugh amount for very little benefit. Image you have 1000 users viewing pages on your site, thats 1000 heartbeat checks per second, for very little benefit. How many other users will you loose becasue of slow page loads becasue your server is busy counting connections.

In short unless you are prepared to undertake a huge amount of development and a lot of trial and error I would forget about this idea.